# How to fix ImportError: No module named pygame

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I was trying to import pygames from python using Canopy firstly and after no success I tried from terminal and in both cases I get:

> > > import pygame
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       ImportError: No module named pygame

I did:

sudo apt-get install python-pygame

and in a desperate act also did the following:

1. sudo apt-get install mercurial python3-pip libfreetype6-dev
2. sudo apt-get build-dep python-pygame
3. sudo pip3 install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame

and when I check on /usr/lib/python2.7 I am able to see a folder named pygame (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygame)

Can someone guide me on how to fix this problem?, thank you in advance

Comment: You're mixing python-2.7 and python3

Comment: Just to be clear, you installed pygame for both Python 2.7 **and** Python 3?

Comment: see that is my problem ... I initially did  sudo apt-get install python-pygame, but since I still got the same problem, did some research and found the other three commands that I executed ... and now I do not know what I have done, or how to fix this mess

Answer (score 1):

Try searching pygame in synaptic package manager.
Install it from there.

Comment: Synaptic is just a graphical front-end in front of apt-get, so this answer isn't really any different from what the OP says they already tried.

Answer (score 0):

I remember pygame giving me a few hours of pain when I installed it on OSX a few months back.

You should be stating which *operating system* you are on, seeing as this is an installation problem. It looks like you are on a bash shell, so I'm guessing Linux.

`which python` and `which python3` will give the respective paths. Your OS typically needs both 2 and 3.

There will be a corresponding `pip` and `pip3`

You've crossed your wires by using `pip3`.

Maybe you can install `pygame` using `pip`... the Python Package Installer?

Googling 'pip pygame' gives https://askubuntu.com/questions/312767/installing-pygame-with-pip

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing pygame using `pip`? (Python Package Index)

If not, type one of the following:

```
pip install pygame
pip3 install pygame
python3 -m pip install pygame
python -m pip install pygame
py -m pip install pygame
```