# pygame error: "ImportError: No module named 'pygame'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

This is my situation:

[image]

I tried importing `pygame` in both python 3.4.2 and python 3.6.3 using both `pip` and `pip3` respectively.

In the python 3.4.2 shell:

> Traceback (most recent call last) is:
>    File "", line 1, in 
>       import pygame
>   ImportError: No module named 'pygame'

In the python 3.6.3 shell:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "", line 1, in 
>       import pygame
>      File "C:\Users\aditya dand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pygame__init__.py", line 141, in 
>       from pygame.base import *
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame.base'

Those are the errors that occurred.

I also used `pygame-1.9.2a0-hg_5974ff8dae3c%2B.win32-py3.4.msi`.
It's showing the header's file of `pygame`, but it's not importing something.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: well the module needs to be installed by the pip associated with the interpreter that IDLE is running... you can print out the contents of sys.path to see what paths your interpreter is searching in...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix ImportError: No module named pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30568176/how-to-fix-importerror-no-module-named-pygame)

Answer (score 2):

Step1:

check http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame to find a Windows installer that matches the version of Python you're running. 
The current version of pygame is : pygame-1.9.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

Move this file to the folder `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts`

=========================================

Step2:

open `cmd`and then type:

```
cd\
cd /d C:\Windows
cd /d C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts
```

and then type the command:

```
pip install pygame
```

Now you have successfully installed pygame package.

=========================================

Step3:

open PyCharm File >> setting
make sure the "Project Interpreter" has the "pygame" package like the following:

[File>>Setting>> make sure the "pygame" package is there.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6fOH.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

check if you have added python to path

Answer (score 0):

ans done if any one need help delete all python version from system and install python 3.5.2 from https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-352/

then go to https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame

and search pygame and download pygame‑1.9.3‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl

then go to C:\Users\"your username"\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts> in this location in cmd ( command prompt )

type this line and done " pip3 install pygame-1.9.3-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl "

hope this help you

Comment: The recommended way to install pygame is to enter `pip3 install pygame` in the command-line. In Windows you can use the Python launcher to specify the Python version `py -3.6 -m pip install pygame`. Also, take a look at the [GettingStarted](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted) page.

Answer (score 0):

Edit - pygame only works in python >= 3.6.*

If you are using Windows i had the same problem and i know how to fix it, follow the steps:

1. Go to the pygame website, then go to the downloads page
2. Once there scroll down to the windows section and copy the bit that
   it says to put into pip It should start with py
3. Once this short piece of code is copied, open command prompt (search
   it on start, it is nothing to do with python)
4. Open it and paste the line of code, it should say downloading and
   then installing and just wait a bit for it to finish. Then in the
   command prompt paste the example.aliens thing in and it should work.
5. Now the complicated part, open file explorer, go to this pc and
   search pygame once it has fully loaded, look near the top if the
   list of things it came up with. There should be 2 thing that are
   called pygame.
6. Now leave this open and hold the windows button and press `r`
7. Then type `%appdata%` and press enter
8. This will open the appdata roming file

   Look at the bit at the top that says `Appdata > roaming` and click on
   app data
9. Then click local, then programs, then python, then `python36` then go
   to scripts
10. Now go back to the pygame search. Click and drag the **2nd** thing
     called pygame into the scripts folder
     and you should be good to go.

> Pls comment if this doesnt make sense or you would like further
>   details

Answer (score 0):

Did you install pygame? You need to type `pip install pygame` or `sudo install pygame` into terminal. If you are using windows 10, press the windows logo key then type terminal. You can check it's installed with: `pygame -H` or `pygame help`

Answer (score 0):

You can either use cmd to install pygame type this
pip install pygame (you have to make sure that python is installed)
If this doesn't help
Use thonny idle I use it because python doesn't work with my pc basically Thonny is a python idle which runs without the requirement of python to be installed and you can also install modules using thonny and type python code as well but make sure that if you import a module in thonny that module can be only used in thonny and can't be used in any other idle unless you install it in cmd but you don't need it as thonny idle is great so if you want to install modules like pygame in thonny 1) Open thonny 2) click on tools 3) click on open shell
There you can type pip install pygame and install it successfully I have a potato pc which can't run python because it requires service pack 1 windows7 or above I don't have it I only have windows 7 so I use thonny and use pygame using thonny only. :D

Answer (score 0):

type this in shell:
py -m pip install -U pygame --user
user is your cmd user.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).