# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pgzrun' when I have it installed?

Tags: python, module, pygame, python-idle

Why does IDLE say

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'`

when I have it installed?
I installed it with pip.
I tried deleting the import but then IDLE gives me a name error saying pygame isn't defined..
I tried doing

```
import pygame
```

and

```
import pgzrun
```

and

```
import pgzero
```

here's my code where its used:

```
import pygame
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
```

I also used a code editor called mu but then if I use functions, it gives me a name error.

Comment: it looks like a miss-configured IDE. If it uses virtual environments, you need to install the dependency on the virtual environment that you are pointing to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pygame error: "ImportError: No module named 'pygame'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51107319/pygame-error-importerror-no-module-named-pygame)

Comment: actually, I looked at that before I asked this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got to `python/scripts` path and try to uninstall it with   `python -m pip uninstall pygame` then install it with `python -m pip install pygame --user`

When installing a python package *without* `--user`, pip defaults to installing it on the system directory such as `/usr/local/lib/python3`, and this requires root access. While when using `--user`, pip installs the package in your home directory which doesn't require any root access or special privileges. So that leaves us with two ways to install Pygame correctly, The first one is to use `--user` to install it without special privileges and the Second choice is to run the terminal as an administrator on Windows or as root on Linux to give it root access for it to download Pygame successfully.

Comment: When installing a python package without --user, pip defaults to installing it on the system directory such as /usr/local/lib/python3, and this requires root access. While when using --user, pip installs the package in your home directory which doesn't require any root access or special privileges.  So that leaves us with two ways to install Pygame correctly, The first one is to use --user to install it without special privileges and the Second choice is to run the terminal as an administrator on Windows or as root on Linux to give  it root access for it to download pygame successfully.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your IDE is using a different version of Python than the one you installed the package to. Try the following to make sure that the package is installed to python 3:

```
pip3 install pygame
```

Some code editors require a restart when new packages are installed.

Comment: Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\program files\python38\python.exe"  "C:\Program Files\Python38\Scripts\pip3.exe" install pygame'

Answer (score 0):

After installing the latest version of python3, do this:

```
python -m pip install pygame==1.9.6
```

This worked for me on macOS High Sierra and Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I think It was a comment somebody made saying it was a miss configured IDE.Now I use spyder  4 And it works fine.

september 17 : Now I figured out that it was actually my path was wrong

Comment: Now I figured out that it was actually my path was wrong